# Android AVD never starts up

Tags: android, eclipse

I just barely installed Android SDK with all the requirements needed to test and develop on it, but there is one problem. Compiling and building the apps works fine, but when I press the run button. This happens.

The emulator is just a black screen with a keyboard.
And this is what the log outputted:

> [2012-05-28 16:04:35 - RedstoneCraft] ------------------------------
>   [2012-05-28 16:04:35 - RedstoneCraft] Android Launch!
>   [2012-05-28 16:04:35 - RedstoneCraft] adb is running normally.
>   [2012-05-28 16:04:35 - RedstoneCraft] Performing mx.x10.redstonecraft.app.RedstoneCraftActivity activity launch
>   [2012-05-28 16:04:35 - RedstoneCraft] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator withh compatible AVD 'Android'
>   [2012-05-28 16:04:35 - RedstoneCraft] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Android'
>   [2012-05-28 16:04:49 - RedstoneCraft] New emulator found: emulator-5554
>   [2012-05-28 16:04:49 - RedstoneCraft] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
>   [2012-05-28 16:06:05 - RedstoneCraft] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'mx.x10.redstonecraft.app.RedstoneCraftActivity activity launch'!

And then when it says emulator-5554 disconnected, thats when the android screen pops up but stays there until I close the emulator. I've tried everything but still no help. :(

Comment: **I've tried everything but still no help.** Did you try waiting for a VERY long time? My dev machine is an old crate and takes at least 5 minutes to start a v2.2 emulator. The first time I tried a v4 emulator it took over 20 minutes. The good thing is with the latest AVD, you can 'snapshot' and it takes much less time to start than the first time. Also make sure you only specify a minimal amount of memory for the external storage / SD card as it will be allocated on your dev machine. I normally only use 32MB at the most. Also, start the AVD first, make sure it's available then use 'run'.

Comment: Yes. I kept it all night and still nothing. And the SD card I kept it on 16 MB

Comment: Delete that AVD and create a new one with the AVD Manager. Make sure you start it first - don't use 'run' from eclipse. Once it's started, use 'run' and it will prompt you for which 'device' to use. Most of us who have ever used AVDs will say it's flakey technology but it can work. Try a v1.6 emulator as well - even with my old crate, a v1.6 emulator loads up in about 1 minute. But again, don't trigger it with 'run' in eclipse - start the AVD first.

Comment: Okay I got it to work without errors. But now its halted here http://pastie.org/3985614

Answer (score -1):

Just close the emulator and restart again.  Even though you get" emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'mx.x10.redstonecraft.app.RedstoneCraftActivity activity launch'!" just try closing the emulator and restarting again. It works.